Entity type cannot be tracked error when updating foreign key via WPF combobox
We have a fairly simple object like this:
[Table("Source")]
public class Source
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column]
    [ForeignKey("Credentials")]
    public int? CredentialsId { get; set; }

    public Credentials? Credentials { get; set; }

    //A bunch of other properties for the Source
}

We allow users to update the Sources properties, including changing the Credentials object that is associated (essentially what username, URL, etc should be used).
This is done via a drop-down in a WPF frontend. The view is like this:
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Credentials, Mode=OneWay}"
          SelectedValue="{Binding Source.Credentials, Mode=TwoWay}" />

And the ViewModel behind this looks like this:
public partial class SourcePropertiesViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    private readonly IRepository repo;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private Source source;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private List<Credentials>? credentials;

    private SourcePropertiesViewModel(IRepository repo, Source source)
    {
        this.repo = repo;
        this.Source = source;
    }

    public static async Task<SourcePropertiesViewModel> CreateAsync(IRepository repo, Source source)
    {
        var vm = new SourcePropertiesViewModel(repo, source);
        await vm.LoadAsync();
        return vm;
    }

    public async Task LoadAsync()
    {
        this.Credentials = await this.repo.GetCredentials();
    }

    public async Task SaveChanges()
    {
        this.repo.Update(this.Source);
        await this.repo.SaveChanges();
    }
}

The IRepository is just a wrapper around a DatabaseContext. For example, GetCredentials is just calling return await this.ctx.Credentials.ToListAsync(); where ctx is a DatabaseContext.
The ObservableObject and [ObservableProperty] attributes are from CommunityToolkit.Mvvm package which simplifies the boiler plate of INotifyPropertyChanged.
When calling SaveChanges() we always hit this error:
System.InvalidOperationException: 'The instance of entity type 'Credentials' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.


My belief is that somewhere between this.Credentials = await this.repo.GetCredentials(); and SelectedItem="{Binding Source.Credentials, Mode=TwoWay}" the object reference is getting lost, so the Source.Credentials ends up being set to a new object which is not in the EF Core Change Tracker... Is that true? If not, what are we doing wrong?

How should we be doing this sort of workflow?


This seems like a really basic thing to being doing in a CRUD application but I can't work out how EF Core wants us to do it instead.

My general advice is "don't mix view models with entities", essentially don't bind to entities. With WPF things can get interesting because the lifetime scope of the DbContext can easily get rather long, leading to performance issues, stale data, or dealing with disconnects.
In your case the first warning flag is this:
public static async Task<SourcePropertiesViewModel> CreateAsync(IRepository repo, Source source)
{
    var vm = new SourcePropertiesViewModel(repo, source);
    await vm.LoadAsync();
    return vm;
}

Here you are passing in the repo which is initialized with a DbContext, and you're passing a Source entity that will be tracked and saved. I assume that the call to LoadAsync is effectively loading the lookup table selection for all credentials and you are using the UI to associate selected credentials to the source before saving it.
The trouble most likely will stem from a disconnect in the Source, and any existing Credentials associated with the Source. The following change would likely work:
public static async Task<SourcePropertiesViewModel> CreateAsync(IRepository repo, int sourceId)
{
    var vm = new SourcePropertiesViewModel(repo);
    await vm.LoadAsync(sourceId);
    return vm;
}

public async Task LoadAsync(sourceId)
{
    this.Source = await this.repo.GetSourceWithCredentialsAsync(sourceId);
    this.Credentials = await this.repo.GetCredentials(); // <- async methods should be suffixed /w "Async"
}

where "GetSourceWithCredentialsAsync" amounts to:
return await ctx.Sources
    .Include(x => x.Credentials)
    .SingleAsync();

This ensures that the Source, its associated credentials, and the list of credentials that might be appended are all tracked by the same DbContext.
Also make sure that when you are adding/removing credentials from the source you are using Add()/Remove() on the Source.Credentials, and not using a public accessor to a setter such as Source.Credentials = selectedCredentials.ToList() or some other form.  To be safe and avoid potential issues, the Source.Credentials navigation property should be:
public virtual ICollection<Credential> Credentials { get; } = [];

This ensures there isn't any tampering with the collection that EF (or the default setup) initializes.

Thanks, changing to getting the Source within the same VM as Credentials rather than passing the Source into the VM seems to have worked. It's going to require a bit of refactoring I think, but at least it works. EF stills feels like a bit of a pain more than it's helped so far, but this is really good advice. Thanks!

It can take a bit of getting used to, but once you have the hang of it, you can save a fair bit of effort. You get the benefit when you design to its strengths. You typically get headaches when you try to get EF to conform to a different or more familiar pattern. The core consideration with EF is that reference equality is everything. It's how EF ultimately knows it is dealing with an existing row or something new.

I still don't really understand why getting the Source and Credentials in the same VM is different from getting the Source and passing it into the VM with Credentials, when both are using the exact same DbContext instance...

If it was the same DbContext instance then it should work, though I suspect the case would have been with any credentials already loaded in that source. It depends entirely on how the source was initially read.  If it was one of many with a .ToList() where AsNoTracking() was added with the expectation to speed it up, that would have caused issues. Passing detached entities around always requires extra care, which is why I always recommend avoiding them in favor of passing simpler view models & loading entities on demand. No surprises / broken keyboards. :)

The Credentials is loaded with return await this.ctx.Credentials.ToListAsync(); so uses ToList(), but no AsNoTracking() there (although I did try that to see what would happen!). I'm thinking perhaps we had some compounded issues.
